# BER curve under BPSK scheme

Tags: matlab, simulation, communication

Hi I have a vector contain how many error bit exist and also I have total number of bits. So I can get BER but since I am using BPSK I use BER=0.5*erfc(sqrt(SNR)) to get the SNR values and then plot them versus each other can anyone help why my result is completely wrong?

```
 Total=279000;
    Error=[9749 10006 10123 10160 10198 10220 10224 10224 10227 10227 ...
      10229 10228 10228 10228 10228 10228 10228 10228 10228];
    BER=Error./Total;
    SNR=(2*erfcinv(BER)).^2
    semilogy(SNR,BER)
```

[image]

Comment: Your code produces a different graph (with a decreasing curve, as it should) than the image in your post

Comment: I asked Matlab to plot that can you tell me what is wrong or what other commands I can use?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Your code produces on my computer a different graph than yours

Comment: Can you please post graph it produces in your computer?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/74nfui5c7/

Comment: Thanks I just tried on different machine and I got your result. I do not know what is wrong with my system

Comment: I am wondering why my curve is a straight line and not a curve like normal BER curve?

Comment: That's because you are using log scale, and also because you are plotting just a small part of the curve